# Proof of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nb_n^2c_n^3<\infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $a_n \geq 0, b_n \geq 0, c_n \geq 0 \; \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ and suppose that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^3b_n^3, \;\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n^3c_n^3, \; \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n^6$ are convergent. Prove that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nb_n^2c_n^3$ is convergent.

I saw that $(a_n^3b_n^3 \cdot b_n^3c_n^3 \cdot c_n^6)^\frac{1}{3}=a_n b_n^2 c_n^3$ and here I stopped.
I was thinking about using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, but I don't really know how to apply it (especially having $x_n^3$, not $x_n^2$).

I would be grateful for some hints! :)

Comment: I did not think too deeply but it seems you have to use smth like AM-GM inequality

Comment: I'm sorry, but are you sure the problem is correctly written? I think we need to find a counter-example :-)

Comment: Actually $(a_n^3\cdot b_n^3c_n^3\cdot c_n^6)^\frac13=a_nb_nc_n^3$

Comment: I am so sorry, i forgot $b_n^3$.It's correct now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apply the Arithmetic Mean - Geometric Mean inequality: $$\frac{a_i^3b_i^3 +b_i^3c_i^3+c_i^6}3\geqslant \sqrt[3]{a_i^3b_i^6c_i^9}=a_ib_i^2c_i^3$$ So your sequence is bounded.

Answer (score 3):

With Hölder's inequality:
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n} a_n b_n^2 c_n^3
&= \sum_{n} a_n b_n \cdot b_n c_n^3\\
&\leq \left(\sum_{n} a_n^3 b_n^3\right)^{1/3}\left(\sum_{n} b_n^{3/2}c_n^{9/2} \right)^{1/3}\\
&= \left(\sum_{n} a_n^3 b_n^3\right)^{1/3}\left(\sum_{n} b_n^{3/2}c_n^{3/2}\cdot c_n^{3} \right)^{1/3}\\
&\leq \left(\sum_{n} a_n^3 b_n^3\right)^{1/3}\left(\sum_{n} b_n^{3}c_n^{3} \right)^{1/6}\left(\sum_{n} c_n^{6} \right)^{1/6} < \infty
\end{align}$$
The first inequality is Hölder's with $p=3,q=3/2$ and the second is Cauchy—Schwarz (i.e., Hölder's with $p=2,q=2$).